# Spring-MVC: Calling a Validator, not from within a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I would like to call a Validator on some object, but not from within a Controller, and then get the Error object.

Could you provide a code sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's docs show how to use Validator without a Controller in sight:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html

Been possible since the beginning.  It's commonly used in Controllers and the web tier, but that's not required.  There's no dependency on the web tier in the validator framework.

Comment: I haven't read the whole text of the linked page, but I looked at the code samples and while nothing there was new I could not see an example of calling `Validator.validate(Object target, Errors errors)` in a non-controller context. I think the difference is that now I have to instantiate the `Errors` by myself, instead of getting it from the Controller (?). But I don't see examples of how to do it... do I use Spring's implementations, and how?

Comment: You're getting the errors from the Validator.  I can't give you an example now, but I'll try later.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but anyone working with spring 2 or spring 3 and wanting to validate components outside the controller, just annotate your class with `@Validated` from package `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated`.
It started using my `@Validate` annotation in all methods of the componentes in the service layer.